# Dialog shown in first activity, not the one that created the fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a main activity and it starts a new activity. This new activity has a fragment which loads it's layout which only has a ListView (extended by my own TableListView):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
        lv = (TableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        return rootView;
        }

    // The Activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_clients);
    findViewById(R.id.container).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    list = new TableFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,list).commit();
    }
```

So far so good. But when I click an item in my TableListView I want to show a dialog box which is shown in the main activity (so it's only visible if I discard the current activity, either manually or with finish()!).

It's like the listview is created within a fragment which runs within the first activity. What could be wrong ?

Edit: It's not related to my custom ListView, still the same problem on an empty fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Dialogs originating from a fragment do not lock to the "current activity", so it's better to pass the dialog creation code to the activity that has loaded the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best bet would be to look into `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` in the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Essentially, you'd start your new activity from your main one, and then when the new activity finishes you can send a certain amount of information back.  From there, you can determine whether you need to open an `AlertDialog` or not.